# Celery: triggering task from within task

Tags: python, celery

When somebody asks about triggering a celery task from another celery task, the usual answer is to use `chain`, e.g.:

```
workflow = celery.chain(first_task.s(a, b), triggered_task.s())
```

However, this seems like an odd fit when the triggered task does not transform the result of the first task. Take an example where you want to do some processing, and then send some email notifications once processing has completed. You could do this using `chain`:

```
@app.task
def processing_task(input):
    return process(input)


@app.task
def send_notifications_task(previous_result):

    message = create_message(previous_result)
    send_to_chat_channel(message)

    return previous_result

processing_workflow = chain(
    processing_task.s(),
    send_notifications_task.s()
)
```

You call this like so:

```
async_result = workflow.delay(input)
```

However, this has some strange properties:

1. The task id for the workflow as a whole ends up being that of the final task in the chain, which is really a task which is incidental to the real work being done.
2. To get the correct result from the workflow, you just have to pass the argument to `send_notifications_task` straight through as its return value. The input isn't processed or transformed in any way.

So, **my first question** is:

In circumstances such as these, is there any reason not to just trigger the second task from within the body of the first, e.g.:

```
    @app.task
    def processing_task(input):
        output = process(input)
        send_notifications_task.delay(output)
        return output
```

My **second question** is: Is there a better way of dealing with this situation that I haven't though of?

Comment: As long as you don't require a definitive order of task execution and you don't need the result of the subtask, I don't see a reason not to simply start the subtask with `.delay()` in your task.

Comment: This is *exactly* the situation I have. Thank you for this question. I plan to just create the task within the first one like you say. Chains feel unwieldy for this.